# Specifying Parameters to Macros

Tags: macros, rpm, rpm-spec

Currently, writing a *.spec file for an RPM. How can I dynamically define variables so that they utilize the parameterized macro?

Per the [rpm documentation](https://docs-old.fedoraproject.org/ro/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch09s07s04.html) I've come up with following:

```
1     %define postgresql_macro() (?%1?%2?%3?%4?%5)
2     %define postgresql_ver %postgresql_macro 9 . 4 . 15
3     %define postgresql_ver_short %postgresql_macro 9 . 4 .
4     %define postgresql_ver_major 9 4
```

Line 1 is the macro that accepts parameters.

Line 2 should define `postgresql_ver` as `9.4.15`.

LIne 3 should define `postgresql_ver_short` as `9.4`.

Line 4 should define `postgresql_ver_major` as `94`.

How can I test this? Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe it's `%{?%1}%{?%2}%{?%3}%{?%4}%{?%5}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have it wrong. it should be:

```
%define postgresql_macro() %1%2%3%4%5                                                                                              
%define postgresql_ver %postgresql_macro 9 . 4 . 15
%define postgresql_ver_short %postgresql_macro 9 . 4 .
%define postgresql_ver_major 9 4
```

You can test this way. Put in your SPEC file:

```
%prep
%define postgresql_macro() %1%2%3%4%5                                                                                              
%define postgresql_ver %postgresql_macro 9 . 4 . 15
%define postgresql_ver_short %postgresql_macro 9 . 4 .
%define postgresql_ver_major 9 4
echo %{postgresql_ver}
```

And now run `rpmbuild -bp your.spec`. This should print: `9.4.15`